# Keep inherited class types with JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using JSON.Net to serialize a set of data so that I could theoretically work on it externally to the project. The structure is as follows:

Zone

- name

- position

- POI [ ]

POI

- name

- position

Town : POI

- population

etc.

I initially serialised the data using JSON.Net, simply calling `JsonConvert.Serialise(myZoneArray)`.
This worked and gave me an appropriate json string which I copied to file.

I then deserialized it, which also succeeded. However, when I call `return this.GetType()` on any of my POI's, they are all returning the base POI class. Thus, I think I am losing the objects inheritance as I serialize and deserialize it.

Are there any existing solutions to this?

Comment: I have found a work around (separate arrays of POI's etc, which are then referenced by ID), however I am still quite interested in the answer for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [tell Json.Net to write and read Type Information](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) by passing in a `JsonSerializerSettings` value for both the write and read steps:

```
static JsonSerializerSettings withTypes= new JsonSerializerSettings
{
  TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
};

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myZoneArray, withTypes);

Console.WriteLine(serialized);

var result= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Zone[]>(serialized,withTypes);
```

Comment: Works perfectly!